# Transfer the value of few bits from one byte to another byte

Tags: java, android, byte, bit

lets say,

```
byte byteOne = 0010 1011;
byte byteTwo = 0110 0000;
```

now i need to move byteOne's last 3 bits to byteTwo's last three bit. Which means have to replace(011)from byteOne & set in byteTwo's 000.

How to do this in single operation?. the value might be dynamic.

Comment: Do you have to modify both `byteOne` and `byteTwo`? Why does it have to be a single operation?

Comment: Are you _copying_ the last three bits from the first byte to the second byte, or are you _swapping_ the last three bits between the two bytes? Or maybe even _moving_ the last three bits of byte one to byte two, leaving `000` as the last three bits of byte one regardless of what was in byte two? Does this _need_ to be a single operation? What do you consider a "single operation"?

Comment: `Which means have to replace(011)from byteOne & set in byteTwo's 000.` ??? No. Which means you have to replace the last three bits of Two with the last three bits of One.

Comment: If the last three bits of Two are always 0 then you can simply add (One & 0x 00000FFF) to Two.

Comment: ****i need to copy only 3 bits from the byteOne and move that value into byteTwo with the same position****

Comment: (byteOne & 0000 0111) | (byteTwo & 1111 1000)

Answer (score 1):

I did using the following snippet

```
   byte byteTwo = (byte) (byteTwo | (byteOne & 0x07));
```

which takes the value from byteOne 3-1 and set it to byteTwo's 3-1

```
0x07 = 0000 0111
//& (AND) - helped to pick the value from byteOne with the help of 0x07
//| (OR) - Helped to set the value to byteTwo the position remains same
```

Thanks guys for the guidance.

Comment: Careful: See what happens with `0010 0101` and `0110 0010`. The result of `b2 | (b1 & 0x07)` will give you `111` in the last three bits, instead of `101` as expected. In other words, this only works if the last three bits of byte two are guaranteed to all be `0`.

Comment: However, [this will work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75829927/transfer-the-value-of-few-bits-from-one-byte-to-another-byte#comment133761446_75829927).